# NgComponent: How to get component instance from DOM element?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've created an `NgComponent` and have declared it in the markup.  Is it possible to query the component element and get the associated `NgComponent` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't need to access controllers via elements. That said, there is [introspection API](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/introspection.dart). `ngDirectives` will return a list of all controller for a given node. ***But AFAIK it's intended for debugging only***.

Alternatively, if you need to access child component/directive/controller consider the following pattern:

```html
<tabs>
  <pane title="Pane A">...</pane>
  <pane title="Pane B">...</pane>
  <pane title="Pane C">...</pane>
</tabs>
```

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'tabs',
    visibility: NgDirective.DIRECT_CHILDREN_VISIBILITY
)
class Tabs {
  List<Pane> _panes;

  registerPane(Pane pane) {
    _panes.add(pane);
  }
}

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'pane'
)
class Pane {
  @NgAttr('title')
  String title;

  Pane(Tabs tabs) {
    tabs.registerPane(this);
  }
}
```

When panes are instantiated they self-register with the tabs container and subsequently tabs container can access pane instances.

Comment: Thanks for the response Pavel.  I'm not trying to access the controller via an element, however.  I'm trying to access the NgComponent instance via the controller.  I've worked around this issue using scope.$broadcast and scope.$on to call the intended method on the component.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to access one component from another?

Comment: I'm trying to access a component from within a controller.

Comment: Angular.dart nomenclature can be confusing sometimes...
So you have a `@NgComponent` and `@NgController` and you want to access the `@NgComponent` from `@NgController`? Is the `@NgController` a child of `@NgComponent`?

Comment: The `NgComponent` is a child of the `NgController`.  So, from within the `NgController` I'm calling `_scope.$broadcast('messageForComponent')` and in the `NgComponent` I'm listening for that message: `_scope.$on('messageForComponent', () => ...)`.  This is working, but my original intent was to get the instance of the `NgComponent` directly.  I was originally doing this in polymer, where you'd `querySelector` the element and it *was* the instance of the component.

Comment: As an alternative you can inject `NgController` in `NgComponent` and then do something like `controller.registerComponent(this)`.

Comment: That would do the trick!  Thanks!  If you edit your question or post another I can mark as the answer.